# Highlighting custom syntactic constructions in WebStorm IDE

Tags: javascript, console, webstorm

My idea is to use specific syntax for comments in **console.log** which would be visible in the code. For example:

```
console.log('<! here is very important comment, don\'t lose it'); // string itself is displayed as green bold text in IDE
// <! here is the sequence for detecting such strings
```

How can I achieve to highlight them with my own styles?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try GrepConsole plugin -- it can apply custom highlighting to whole lines/selected text based on regex patterns. Maybe it will work for JavaScript console as well (I have never tried it there). But .. if you want to highlight such stuff in actual code ... then it's not possible. Maybe use TODO comments (have separate colors to ordinary comment) or bookmarks instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have highlighting of custom functions/keywords with current functionality.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473 and related tickets -- watch them (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

The best I can suggest here right now is to use [TODO comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/todo-example.html?search=todo): custom markers and colors will give you the enough visibility.

Alternatively -- try Bookmarks. They will not highlight the code .. but will give markers on scrollbar and navigation in View Bookmarks window.

Comment: Thank you for understanding! I tried to solve my problem through built-in settings, but unsuccessful.

I think that there is a tricky thing that may help: file watcher that watches file and adds TODO/FIXME comment above my console.log when it occurs in code (with text from that console.log). I think it can be easy to implement this on the bash + awk.